# Callback not getting called even though it should

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

I have a model with a simple `:after_update` callback that is not firing for some reason.  I have a test that checks whether the function is called and it passes, but for some reason nothing actually happens.

```
class HealthProfile < ApplicationRecord

    after_update :send_office_email

    def send_office_email
        p "sending office email"
        email = MailjetService.new(ID)

        Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'host_name'

        message = email.send_email('email', self.location.email, "New Health Profile: #{self.name}", {
            "office_name" => self.location.name,
            "name" => self.name,
            "url" => Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.health_profile_url(self)
        })

        p message
    end
end
```

**Test:**

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe HealthProfile, type: :model do

    before(:each) do
        @hp = build(:health_profile)
    end

    it 'emails office on update (complete - w/ signature)' do
        p 1
        @hp.save
        p 2
        expect(@hp).to receive(:send_office_email)
        p "updating signature to true..."
        @hp.update(signature: 't')
        p 3
    end
end
```

In my test output I see the following:

```
1
2
"updating signature to true..."
3
```

But I never see `sending office email`.  The test passes, showing that the model received the callback, but nothing in the callback ran.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I believe your test is working. If it wasn't your test would be failing with `expected to receive "send_office_email" but nothing was called`.

`expect to_receive` is stubbing the method on the object which results in a dummy method that doesn't call your original method.

Try this.

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe HealthProfile, type: :model do

    let(:hp) { build(:health_profile) }

    it 'emails office on update (complete - w/ signature)' do
        p 1
        hp.save
        p 2
        p "updating signature to true..."
        hp.update(signature: 't')
        p 3
    end
end
```

Comment: in addition to baylor rae answer, you can check if your mail queue has got any mail to process or not after you update your signature. Then you can be fully confirmed